# How can I execute terminal script/command in Google Compute Instance remotely from my React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is it possible to execute a script remotely on Google Compute Engine (GCE) instance from my react app?

For example, I would upload a file to google cloud storage, then I have some script executed remotely that read the uploaded file and modify it (adding some metadata, etc.)

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

For executing a script remotely, you have to be connected to the VM. For me, the easiest way is to deploy an endpoint on the VM (what ever is it, but think to secure it with SSL and authentication).

Then, call this endpoint with your react app. The endpoint can spawn scripts on the VM.

In case of storage, you can

- Set an [event that trigger a Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage)
- The Cloud Function call the endpoint exposed on your VM
- Plug a [serverless VPC Connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) to your function for reaching privately your VM (no public IP required). This is the most secure way.

**UPDATE**

Here the code to set on your vm:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var exec = require('child_process').exec;
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //Change the script. Here it's pwd, set what you want
    exec('pwd', function callback(error, stdout, stderr){
    //Handle here the output of your bash script 
    res.send(stdout)
   })
   res.statusCode=200;
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {});
```

On your VM, install `nodejs` and `express`. Then run `node index.js`. You can customize the port by setting the env variable `PORT` at the value that you want. Else it's 8080 by default.

Open the required firewall rule to your VM for allowing a call to your express server.

Here there is neither SSL on the server nor authentication, even basic.

Comment: Thank you for this exciting answer. By the way, can you elaborate more/give some tips how to deploy an endpoint on the VM and access it via my react app?

Comment: What's your prefered language? I can do it in Python, Java or Go. Node also, but with dirty code. Just confirm me, your react app can make http call?

Comment: Of course. I prefer to write in JS right now, but I am comfortable with Python and Java. Can you share me some sample code regarding that?

Comment: I added a NodeJS code. Of course, you can customize the query with params if you want. Tell me if you need more precision and if it solves your use case.